# How to efficiently normalize vector C++

Tags: c++, performance, normalization

I want to know how to efficiently normalize a vector in C++. So far, this is what I have. Is there a way to make it more efficient and / or do it in a single pass.

```cpp
std::array<float, MyClass::FEATURE_LENGTH> MyClass::normalize(const std::array<float, FEATURE_LENGTH>& arr) {
    std::array<float, MyClass::FEATURE_LENGTH> output{};
    double mod = 0.0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        mod += arr[i] * arr[i];
    }

    double mag = std::sqrt(mod);

    if (mag == 0) {
        throw std::logic_error("The input vector is a zero vector");
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        output[i] = arr[i] / mag;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered to normalize the vector inplace? Creating a new Array can cause an allocation, which is costly.

Comment: If your target architechture supports SIMD instruction this can also improve your performance. Try compiling with "-march=native" and/or the use of intrinsics or a vectorization library.

Comment: Have you cranked up the optimizer? The tricks I'd recommend here are well known to the compiler developers and they're probably using all of them.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It is clear, nontrivial and provides a self contained example.

Comment: @OutOfBound Only reason I can think of is this question is a bit better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Stack Overflow is great for problems with code that doesn't work. Code Review is  intended for "My code works, but how do I make it better?" questions. Note I linked to the help pages. This is in case the asker wishes to delete this question and ask again at Code Review; they should give the asking section a read-through first in order to get the best possible reception.

Comment: @OutOfBound `std::array` never allocates dynamic memory.

Comment: A standard technique is to do 2 computations in half as many iterations.  (The problem is the "end case" of having an odd number of items.)  The purpose is to cut in half the overhead of the looping code _and_ to give the compiler more optimizations to try -- such as running 2 multiples simultaneously.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that no algorithmic optimizations are possible. That leaves the various suggested micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to optimize implementations of this algorithm, depending on the particulars of your problem.

1. For all of your loops, you can use SIMD vectorization to increase throughput.
2. If your vectors are *very* wide then you can use multiple threads to compute the magnitude. Each would compute a partial sum, then some serial code would collect the results.
3. You can work entirely in floats, rather than doubles, if your values are within range.
4. You can compute the inverse square root of the magnitude by using intrinsics (such as [RSQRTSS](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rsqrtss) on x86) or using [Quake's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) if such intrinsics are unavailable. Then you would scale by that value.

Additionally, you can get **much** faster code by fusing operations with the normalization. Say you want to add two vectors and normalize the result. You can compute their sum and their magnitude in a single pass and then scale in a second.

Answer (score 2):

How can you do it in a single pass. It is obvious than you need to compute `mag` using all items and that you must have compute it before updating items?

As it might more take to do a division than a multiplication, one possible optimization would be to add:

```
double mag_inv = 1.0 / mag;
```

Then you could multiply items like that:

```
output[i] = arr[i] * mag_inv;
```

If there is a relatively high probability that a vector is already normalized, you might want to check if `mag` is equal to 1.0.

Comment: (This is assuming that a divide is slower than a multiply.  Such is the case for all hardware I can think of.)

Comment: Because `mag` is loop-invariant, GCC will do that change automatically when compiling with `-Ofast`

Comment: @AlexReinking Optimization are compiler and option dependant. And some compilers have "fast math" option that are not IEEE compliant but allow faster code.

Comment: @Phil1970 - yes, I am aware. That's what `-Ofast` enables. I am merely observing that the transformation you gave in your answer (converting division to multiplication) is both not IEEE compliant and able to be performed automatically when such flags are set. This is relevant because if OP is compiling with fast math, this will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In case, if someone needs it here's an example of SIMD vectorization code:

```
#include <immintrin.h> //header for SIMD functions

void Normalize(const float lpInput[4], float lpOutput[4]) {
    __m128 vInput = _mm_load_ps(lpInput); // load input vector (x, y, z, a)
    __m128 vSquared = _mm_mul_ps(vInput, vInput); // square the input values
    __m128 vHalfSum = _mm_hadd_ps(vSquared, vSquared); 
    __m128 vSum = _mm_hadd_ps(vHalfSum, vHalfSum); // compute the sum of values
    float fInvSqrt; _mm_store_ss(&fInvSqrt, _mm_rsqrt_ss(vSum)); // compute the inverse sqrt
    __m128 vNormalized = _mm_mul_ps(vInput, _mm_set1_ps(fInvSqrt)); // normalize the input vector
    _mm_store_ps(lpOutput, vNormalized); // store normalized vector (x, y, z, a)
}
```

In order to compile it properly you'll need to enable SSE and AVX instructions in compiler options (-msse -mavx for gcc or clang || /arch:sse /arch:avx for msvc)

Comment: That's not a particularly good normalisation routine for an *arbitrary* length vector - this only handles the 4D case. You assume the input & output are 16byte aligned (might not be). It's using rsqrt, so it's going to lose a tonne of accuracy (might be ok for a surface normal, but will fail in many ray-tracing cases due to lack of accuracy). Nothing in that code requires AVX. Why are you using _mm_store_ss here? _mm_cvtss_f32 is the right way. Each element in vSum will be the same, so _mm_rqsrt_ps(vSum) would avoid the store and broadcast. _mm_dp_ps would be an even better option here.

Comment: this is an entry level question about normalizing a fixed length vector, so chill. And this is still considered higher level code, not direct assembly code. O3 optimization would use some form of broadcasting a single value to the whole vector instead of store\set.